# MySQL select all rows from last N groups

Tags: mysql, sql, database, group-by, sqlalchemy

I have a dataset like this, where there can be multiple transactions per trade

```
| tx_id | trade_id |
--------------------
| 100   | 11       |
| 99    | 11       |
| 98    | 11       |
| 97    | 10       |
| 96    | 10       |
| 95    | 9        |
| 94    | 9        |
| 93    | 8        |
...
```

I want to select all of the transactions from the last N trades. For instance if I wanted to select all rows from the last 2 trades, I would get:

```
| tx_id | trade_id |
--------------------
| 100   | 11       |
| 99    | 11       |
| 98    | 11       |
| 97    | 10       |
| 96    | 10       |
```

I cannot guarantee that the `trade_id` will always have an interval of 1.

How can I accomplish this in mysql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `DENSE_RANK` on `trade_id` descending, then filter on your required X for "last X":

```
CREATE TABLE t (tx_id int, trade_id int);

INSERT INTO t (tx_id, trade_id) VALUES
(100,11),
(99,11),
(98,11),
(97,10),
(96,10),
(95,9),
(94,9),
(93,8);

SET @ngroups=2;

WITH dat
AS
(
SELECT tx_id, trade_id, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY trade_id DESC) AS trade_id_rank
FROM t
)
SELECT tx_id, trade_id
FROM dat
WHERE trade_id_rank <= @ngroups;
```

[dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a394283cbdf718d710249973e30ea954)

Answer (score 3):

This will also work with mysql 5

Changing the linit , you can choose how many trades you want to receive

> ```
> CREATE TABLE tab1 (
>   `tx_id` INTEGER,
>   `trade_id` INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO tab1
>   (`tx_id`, `trade_id`)
> VALUES
>   ('100', '11'),
>   ('99', '11'),
>   ('98', '11'),
>   ('97', '10'),
>   ('96', '10'),
>   ('95', '9'),
>   ('94', '9'),
>   ('93', '8');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT t1.* FROM tab1 t1 JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT `trade_id` FROM tab1 ORDER BY `trade_id`  DESC LIMIT 2) t2
> ON t1.`trade_id` = t2.`trade_id`
> ```
>
> ```
> tx_id | trade_id
> ----: | -------:
>   100 |       11
>    99 |       11
>    98 |       11
>    97 |       10
>    96 |       10
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3644699c322579b905c0975ebf96f4d0)*

Answer (score 2):

If we assume the "last trades" are the ones with the highest `trade_id` numbers, then you can use `DENSE_RANK()`.

For example:

```
select *
from (
  select *,
    dense_rank() over(order by trade_id desc) as dr
  from t
) x
where dr <= 2
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with a CTE

```
WITH trades AS
SELECT trade_id tid
FROM myTable
GROUP BY trade_id
ORDER BY trade_id
LIMIT 2
SELECT * FROM
trades 
JOIN myTable ON trade_id = tid
ORDER BY tx_id;
```